# Logitech Keyboard K800 not configured properly

Tags: kernel, keyboard-layout, logitech

Running ubuntu 16.04 LTS on 
AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 240 Processor × 2
Kernel:
Linux jg-MS-7596 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The keyboard symbol keys are mixed up or not working at all. I can reconfigure the keyboard with command:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration.

I have to do this after each system reboot.
How can I make the reconfiguration permanent?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. Doesn't the desired configuration get saved in `/etc/default/keyboard` when you run that command?

Comment: I checked with: /etc/default$ ls -al
total 140
 and there is among others:     -rw-rw-r--   1 root root   158 Jul 19 12:26 keyboard     vi keyboard says:   # KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="logitech_base"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"

Comment: It was `/etc/default/keyboard` I was talking about. Confusing line break. ;)

Comment: sorry for the confusion...I found the file keyboard in /etc/default...how do I know if this is the correct content?                                       
                                                                                                                       #KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="logitech_base"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"

Comment: That means the _Logitech Generic Keyboard_ model and the _English (US)_ keyboard layout. Is that what you choose when running the dpkg-reconfigure command?

Comment: Yes,   because I couldn't find the Logitech K800.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62494/discussion-between-jgrau-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).